# How to target specific text content in a paragraph which contains multiple line breaks?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, line-breaks

So here is the weird thing I am clueless on..

Below is the sample snippet of the HTML,

```
<p>This is a paragraph with <br><br> two weird line breaks <br><br> and that too TWICE!</p>
```

Now the issue is, I want to apply CSS to the text `This is paragraph`  OR the content after first-double line breaks.

I tried `br + br` or nth-selectors, all css selectors I could think of, but it didn't worked out.

Tricky part is, I do not want to do by javascript, or else I would have done it easily accompanied by 'complexity'.

Any hints or solution to this problem by CSS ONLY!!

Thanks!

Comment: the br selector won't work, since br's can't have any text

Comment: If you want to style specific text that text has to be in an element (with the exception of `"This is a paragraph with"`, given that it could (probably) [be targeted with the `::first-line` pseudo-element](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wnz7xx3u/)). Given that, the only realistic way to achieve this is to wrap the given text in specific elements, and then target those.

Comment: @JacobGray I was trying to target the text after br's, well thanks!

Comment: @DavidThomas Indeed I would have done like that.. but ::firstline selector only works when you actually want to target first line, in my cased it would a huge paragraph. I am constaint to do so because the data/html is being generated by the independent resource feed system. Appreciate your opinion. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible without using JavaScript to wrap the given text in an element, and to style that element using either CSS (with a selector) or with JavaScript (adding a class or directly updating the style).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by adding in HTML.  I dont think there is a CSS specific way to do this.

`<p><span id="snippet">This is a paragraph with </span><br><br> two weird line breaks <br><br> and that too TWICE!</p>`

Then apply your CSS like this

```
#snippet{
//css styles go here
}
```

Comment: I do not have any control over the html, or else why would I add double line-breaks in first place, instead when I can do multiple p's inside a div. the html is generated from a different feeder system. Thanks though :)